# Generating signed apk getting error on inflating BottomNavigationView after switching to androidX

Tags: android, xml, bottomnavigationview, androidx

App crashes with error error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView when generating signed apk. Running the app with debug apk from android studio directly to device has no problem. I have migrated my project to androidX as well.

I've read some other post saying the drawable or colors might have problem so I've confirm that there are no other drawable folders (e.g. drawable-v21, drawable-v24). Im not sure why but it only happens when I generate a signed apk.

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawable_selector"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawable_selector"
app:itemBackground="@color/primary"
```

but it doesn't work

line 15 error starts here:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/drawable_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/drawable_selector"
    app:itemBackground="@color/primary"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>
```

have already included this in my gradle:
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Are you using material theme for your app? It will crash if not.

Comment: @ror how do i check if my app is using material theme? Thanks

Comment: First pls check manifest of your application - there should be something like android:theme="@style/***" under <application> tag. If that's there, Just Ctrl+B on it to navigate to declaration. Once there (under styles.xml), pls check what is the parent of your style and share here.

Comment: @ror this is my style in the style.xml


     <style name="NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: I believe that's your problem. Try using Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar as parent theme.